# Image cannot be displayed in spring application

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have write a simple Spring + Angular application just for learn more about it. 
I have a spring controller which is mapped to a URL and when an request comes it returns an image.

I have written all the codes and the spring controller returns me the image but when i set it in the HTML it is not displayed correctly

here is my spring controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "image/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ResponseEntity<byte[]>  getChequeImage(HttpSessionsession,@PathVariable("itemId") Integer itemId,
                                    HttpServletResponse response) {

    try{
        InputStream in =  new FileInputStream(new File("path_to_image.jpg"));

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);

        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), headers, HttpStatus.OK);

    }catch (IOException e){
        LOGGER.error(e);
        e.getMessage(), response);
        return null;
    }


}
```

here is my HTML code

```
<img src="{{image}}"/>
```

image is an Angular variable. Angular service is sending the request and binding the data to the image variable

here is the angular code

```
@scope.image = "data:image/jpg," + data_from_the_api;
```

Comment: Do you see any error in console, like "Cannot find resource " ??

Comment: @TechMa9iac No errors were displayed in the console when i look through it I can see the byte stream in the response

Comment: Try adding @scope.image = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data_from_the_api;

Comment: @TechMa9iac thanks for the help, I tried it but it is not working,

Comment: Can you post a plunker for it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use raw image bytes directly on the page, but you can do Base64 encoding, this would be the adaptations

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "image/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ResponseEntity<String>  getChequeImage(HttpSessionsession,@PathVariable("itemId") Integer itemId,
                                    HttpServletResponse response) {

    try{
        InputStream in =  new FileInputStream(new File("path_to_image.jpg"));

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        byte[] binaryData = IOUtils.toByteArray(in)
        byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(binaryData);
        String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(base64Encoded , headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch (IOException e){
        LOGGER.error(e);
        e.getMessage(), response);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and as TechMa9iac said in the comment you should set `@scope.image = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data_from_the_api;`

Comment: Thanks this was helpful and i used to manage to do this. but also i did some adjustment to your answer. since I'm using Angular, when a string directly come from the API it deserialize the sting like this 

   {
    "0" : "V",
    "1" : "a",
    "2" : "l",
    "3" : "u",
    "4" : "e",
    "5" : "_",
    "6" : "2"
  }

To avoid that i made the String as you said and then wrap it in a object and then send to the front end.

and then i accessed the encoded string as @TechMa9iac mentioned 

Hope this comment will help for the future users